# Is it possible to use Entity Framework Code First with Web Forms (Asp.NET)?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, ef-code-first

It is possible to use ASP.net EF Code first approach with Web Forms 4.5.2 ? I am currently using web forms to database first and would love to switch to code first approach.

Answer (score 2):

Whether it is a console application or a complex engine project, the Data Access Layer can have any approach. So the direct answer is: yes you can.

You can [generate code first classes and context from an existing database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx)

All you need is to install Entity Framework 6.x (if not already done), then follow these instructions:

> **3.Reverse Engineer Model**
>
> `Project` > `Add New Item…`
>
> Select `Data` from the left menu and then `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`.
>
> Enter `BloggingContext` as the name and click `OK`.
>
> This launches the **Entity Data Model Wizard**. Select `Code First from Database` and click `Next`.

Follow the wizard and it will generate the models and context with the connection

Comment: How does the migration work. Any tutorials you can provide

Comment: Migrations are pretty simple [here is one of the tutorials](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/entityframework/understanding-entity-framework-code-first-migrations) .. you'll find most basic questions already answered here

Comment: @irfandar Microsoft has not properly documented migrations (unless it has been written after I asked [Code First Migrations documentation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/719190b6-0627-42c0-ba57-791259b53ee1/code-first-migrations-documentation)) and therefore might not be simple to understand. This however is not the place to ask about migrations.